# RESTAPI implementation with ORM and nodejs express

Tags: node.js, orm

I am thinking of implementing Postgres backend with nodejs express and bookshelf ORM.

The question that I have for you all - which ORM are you guys currently using and why?

What is my need:

An ORM that support what RDMS has to offer.

It should support Postgres.

Minimal learning curve.

Easy to integrate with Node/ Express

Good documentations and community support.

At some point I will be using Memcached (http://memcached.org/) that it should be compatible with.

Comment: Can anyone please shed some lights?